# problem in publishing a webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, iis, publishing

i am new to web services. i have created a web service in .net. it's working fine but i am bit confused about the publishing procedure.

it's not working when i publish it to localhost's inetpub.i get some error messages like access denied or location not found.

i wanna know the procedure to publish my webservice and make it public.

the answer would be more helpful if it has some screenshots or screencasts.

thanks in advance

Comment: using asmx i guess. i am totally new to webservice environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ussually you do not need to publish to localhist, run is enough to test it (F5).

When I need to publish I am using publish to Folder, like C:\Publish\MyService, and than upload result to your web server manually